# Как в DetailView отобразить отформатированный массив?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть у меня поле в модели с Json строкой. Как ей можно отобразить в как отоформатированный массив в `DetailView::widget`?  То есть мне нужно сделать тоже самое, что конструкция

```
echo '<pre>'
print_r(json_decode($array, true));
echo '</pre>'
```

но только в значении виджета.

Конструкция вида

```
[
        'attribute' => 'old_values',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value' => function($model) {
        return print_r(json_encode($model->old_values, true));
    }
],
```

не дает нужного результата

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока сделал так:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'old_values',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function($model) {
        ob_start();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r(json_decode($model->old_values, true));
        echo '</pre>';

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
],
```

Возможно есть решение лучше

Answer (score 0):

return print_r(json_decode($array, true), true);

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.print-r.php

Comment: Не, пробовал изначально сразу. Он этот вывод делается где-то вверху страницы. Поэтому в своем ответе я сделал буферизацию и `pre` для нормального отображения в стобик

Comment: Второй параметр в print_r нужно установить в true, тогда вывод будет не на экран.